# Replace comma with new line in MacOS terminal bash shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to replace each comma with a new line.

e.g. when I do the following

```
echo abc,wer | sed 's/\,/\n/g'
```

I hope to get

```
abc
wer
```

However, I got

```
abcnwer
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Dang! It works as expected in GNU/Linux bash. Did you also try \\n?

Comment: Oh gosh... Why did my MacOS don't return the right result :(

Comment: macOS is based on BSD behaviour. You can use `tr` here `echo abc,wer | tr , '\n'`

Comment: Nice one! Got it working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @MarkSetchell answer above, the below works.

```
echo abc,wer | tr , '\n'
```